# Acceso a atributos de objetos mediante notación punto

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo un dataframe de Pandas con una columna de fechas y otra correspondiente a las mediciones de temperatura correspondientes. Si el encabezado de esta ultima columna fuera `Tem`, para acceder a ella podría hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
valores_tem = df.Tem
```

La cuestión es la siguiente: si a una variable `nombre_variable` le asigno el encabezado de la ultima columna del dataframe, e intento algo como

```
nombre_variable = 'Tem'
valores = df.nombre_variable
```

obviamente me aparece un AttributeError porque el dataframe no tiene un atributo llamado `nombre_variable`.

¿Existe alguna manera de acceder a atributos mediante una variable que contenga el nombre del atributo que uno quiere extraer y que le permita hacerlo mediante la notación punto (df.nombre_variable)?

NOTA: En este caso usé un dataframe de pandas porque es en lo que estoy trabajando actualmente, pero la cuestión se puede extender al acceso de atributos de objetos en general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres llamar un atributo desde un nombre usa [getattr()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/getattr)

```
nombre_variable = 'Tem'
valores = getattr(df,nombre_variable)
```

Donde `getattr(object, variable_name, default)` `object` es el objeto que lo contiene, `variable_name`es el nombre del atributo y `default` el valor por default que tendrá en caso de no existir un atributo con ese nombre en el objeto, este último se puede omitir

Comment: Excelente, algo así es lo que estaba buscando. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la indexación mediante corchetes cuadrados para acceder a columnas en DataFrames de Pandas. Por lo que podrías hacer exitosamente:

```
nombre_columna= 'Tem'
valores = df[nombre_columna]
```

De no existir esa columna hará `raise` de un `KeyError`, pero si existe debería funcionar; tal y como como un diccionario.

Ahora para cualquier otro objeto, propongo una solución ad-hoc consistente en implementar el metodo `__getitem__` para hacer override del comportamiento de indexacion mediante corchetes cuadrados para ese objeto:

```
class Test(object):     
    def __getitem__(self, arg):
        """
        @param arg: lo que está entre corchetes cuadrados
        """
        if arg == 'Tem':
           return self.Tem
        return None
Test.Tem == Test['Tem']  # True
```

Si no quieres implementar algo asi, también puedes utilizar el atributo `__dict__` de los objetos. Te invito a leer [este tutorial para más información.](https://codesachin.wordpress.com/2016/06/09/the-magic-behind-attribute-access-in-python/)

Espero haberte ayudado, quedo atento a más comentarios

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, la tendré en consideración.